# Feedback on Object-Oriented ETL Class Structure for Computing Profit Summary Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, pandas

I am using Python 3 and pandas 0.24.2 to do some data processing and ETL flows. I have followed this pattern a couple of times and it is really bothering me but I am not sure which direction to go to majorly improve it. Any advice for what to do differently is greatly appreciated. This is a toy example but the logic is the same. The main method is below. How can the structure of the class be improved?

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import deque
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import namedtuple
from src.query_helper import postgres_query_helper as pgqh

class ComputeNetProfitSummary():
    def __init__(self, date=None, factory_id=None):
        self.date = date
        self.factory_id = factory_id
        self.pg_query_helper = pgqh.PostgresQueryHelper()

    def build_sql_query(self):
        sql_query = f"""Select * FROM factory_table
            WHERE date='{self.date}' 
            AND factory_id={self.factory_id}
        """
        return sql_query

    def create_orders_df(self):
        """Create orders Data Frame"""
        if self.date and self.factory_id:  
            sql_query = self.build_sql_query()       
            df = self.pg_query_helper.execute_sql_return_df(sql_query)
            return df

    def compute_complex_metrics_on_df(self):
        """Some complicated logic using FIFO attribution"""
        ComplexData = namedtuple('ComplexData', ['ColumnNamesA', ..., 'ColumnNamesZ'])      
        all_data = []  

        for row in self.orders_df.iterrows():
            """Do complicated stuff"""
            transform_row = # some computations on row
            complex_output = ComplexData(transform_row)
            all_data.append(complex_output)

        complex_df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
        return complex_df 

    def compute_summary_statistics(self):
        """Compute summary data"""
        summary_data = defaultdict(dict)
        # Create summary data, I am fine with this
        return summary_data 

    def compute_summary_data(self):
        self.orders_df = self.create_orders_df()
        self.complex_df = compute_complex_metrics_on_df()
        self.summary_statistics = compute_summary_statistics()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cnp = ComputeNetProfitSummary(date='2019-01-01', factory_id='A')

    summary_data = cnp.compute_summary_data()

    for key, value in summary_data.items():
        print(key)
        print(value)
```

NOTE: I am one of the only Python developers on my team so I do not get a lot of feedback on this type of code very often. Any feedback or constructive criticism is welcome, from design patterns to PEP8.